# WP white icons in taskbar

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10-mobile

I'm quite new to windows universal app, I started to design my first app few days ago and I have problem setting white icons in task bar. It was easy in windows 8.1 but here no matter what I set for theme, battery, clock...always dark.
Does anyone know how to change color?

Thanks

[image: How app look now]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
var statusBar = StatusBar.GetForCurrentView();
```

Then set the *ForegroundColor*.

```
statusBar.ForegroundColor = Colors.White;
```

Sadly, it can no longer be done from Xaml without additional code.

Comment: Thanks, I feel really stupid to ask that, but where to put that code? And what foreground color? 

Thanks for all your time

Comment: Either in App.Xaml.cs or in your pages CodeBehind. That method returns a 'StatusBar' object on which you can set the Foreground color.

Comment: Thanks again, I'm trying but it keeps telling me something is wrong, as I said I'm quite new to that, should I make a new method? Or add library?

Comment: Anywhere I try it underline it as wrong "StatusBar."

Comment: You probably have to add the using statements. VS does that for you by placing the cursor in the underlined word and then hitting strg+. (dot).

Comment: But if that stops you already, I'd recommend checking out some basic C# courses, for example at Microsoft Virtual Academy.

Comment: Thanks for your answer again, I was watching many courses on that website, I'm far away from pro user, but I can do some simple stuff in form application. I tried what you said already and it doesn't give me a "using" option. Sorry if I'm asking stupid questions, I have done most of my program already, but building UI around make problem since in school we didn't really focus much on that. If you find some more time, I would appreciate your answer, happy holidays.

Answer (score 3):

Although the answer you accepted is correct and you'll need the extension, it's better to 'not' check on device family. Because it could be that in the future this would change and other devices can also have the status bar! So use this to verify if one is available:

```
if (Windows.Foundation.Metadata.ApiInformation.IsTypePresent("Windows.UI.ViewManagement.StatusBar")) { ... }
```

Comment: up! since you should always check on contracts instead of device family.

Comment: Thanks, I would give an "up" too but I don't have reputation high enough yet.

Comment: I'd edit not to say that the other is correct. Adding the mobile extensions is correct, but using AnalyticsInfo instead of ApiInformation is quite wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the catch @RobCaplan-MSFT , missed that :)

Answer (score -1):

You want to write code that runs only on a specific device family, in your case is Windows Mobile. To do that, add **Window Mobile Extensions for the UWP**.

[image]

<s>As mentioned above you can add code in App.xaml.cs. It's oke, but I recommend first to check which platform will be used.</s>

<s>Here is a small snippet:</s>

```
private void InitializeThemes()
    {
        switch (AnalyticsInfo.VersionInfo.DeviceFamily)
        {
            case "Windows.Mobile":
                StatusBar statusBar = StatusBar.GetForCurrentView();

                break;
            case "Windows.Desktop":
                ApplicationView applicationView = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView();

                break;
        }
    }
```

As mentioned in the comments, the above solution is not suitable in your situation. Instead use the method that was described in @Depechie answer.

Comment: Hi, thanks for you answer I'm sure it will help many new developers. Can I just ask you where in VS you dowload those Extensions. Thanks

Comment: @Laurent Resman I assume that you have it already. Right click on project -> Add --> Reference --> Universal Windows --> Extensions --> Windows Mobile Extensions for the UWP.

Comment: Switching on DeviceFamily is quite wrong. Use AnalyticsInfo only for analytics, not for functionality. The right way us to use ApiInformation to check if the class or contract exists.